# Element not found by name/id on selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to login in Mathwork account but have this error message "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'"

Here is the source of login page of Mathwork:

[image: name]

and

[image]

I have tried to different lines of code below, but to no avail:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='userId']")
username = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
username = driver.find_element_by_id('userId')
```

Here is my full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\Dung Le\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://www.mathworks.com/login?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fhelp%2Findex.html%3Fs_tid%3DCRUX_lftnav')
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
username = driver.find_element_by_name('userId')
username.send_keys('my_email')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
time.sleep(2)
password.send_keys('my_password')
```

I received this error:

> "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "C:/Users/Dung Le/PycharmProjects/untitled7/dsd.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Dung Le/PycharmProjects/untitled7/dsd.py", line 11, in 
>       username.send_keys('leanh***@gmail.com')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

and this output:

[image]

I expect to resolve this error and has my login information in the input space of the login page.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code you're using? `find_element_by_name('userId')` didn't raise a `NoSuchElement` exception, so it did find the element.  I don't understand how it can successfully find the element but still return `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check if the element is in the main content or in a frame, if the element is in a frame, you have to switch to that frame first:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('me')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_id('userId').send_keys('blablabla')
```

after you are done with the frame, switch back to the default content

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```